# What is the meaning and command executed on Ctrl+Alt+Del in Linux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, logout, reboot

In my gnome GUI desktop of Ubuntu 12.04, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> will log out instead of rebooting.

But I was told that

> Switching to a text-based virtual console and pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete
>   will reboot the machine. It will shut down cleanly and reboot, which
>   is much better than Alt+SysRq+REISUB.

So I wonder if the above two different meanings of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> are right?

What commands <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is binded to in these two cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> is actually a "magic" keystroke for the IBM PC-compatible hardware architecture that would call a BIOS reset.

Since this kind of thing is dangerous for a system like Linux the decision was made to hook those keystrokes and do something else instead. This is controlled by `init` and you can see what it does by looking in `/etc/inittab`.

On my Debian Squeeze system:

```
ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now
```

Windows NT later followed suit and turned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> into the secure key entry mode*.

In the case of X, it is similarly hooking the keystrokes but it simply `kill`s the display server (which will automatically respawn if you're using a display manager).

Some systems (perhaps all, I haven't tried in a while) you can still press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> before the OS loads to trigger a BIOS reset.

---

*I'm not sure what they actually call it.

Comment: Thanks! What is `/etc/inittab` used for?

Comment: @Tim: `/etc/inittab` is more or less the config file for `init`.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 12.04, there is no /etc/inittab. What might possibly be the alternative?

Comment: Mm, that's right. Ubuntu uses `upstart` rather than `init`. The equivalent on Ubuntu is the [`etc/init`](http://askubuntu.com/a/34310) directory. (Note *not* `/etc/init.d`).

Comment: (1) WHich file in /etc/init should I look for? (2) I don't find a command called upstart in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Tim `/etc/init/control-alt-delete.conf` As for upstart, upstart is still *called* `init`, but it's not the traditional `init`. See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) and [the project page](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: You probably mean a BIOS reset?

Answer (score 2):

**The Linux kernel can either hard reboot or send SIGINT the init process upon Ctrl + Alt + Del**

The Linux kernel itself allows two possible behaviors from Ctrl-Alt-Del:

- reboot immediately
- send SIGINT to the init process

Which behavior is used can be selected with either:

- `reboot` system call, see `man 2 reboot`
- `/proc/sys/kernel/ctrl-alt-del`

Therefore, if the SIGINT behaviour is enabled, then the outcome of Ctrl + Alt + Del depends entirely on the SIGINT handler that your init has.

For example, BusyBox' 1.28.3 init execs an arbitrary command given in `/etc/inittab` as:

```
::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot
```

And here is a minimal interesting C example for uclibc:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/reboot.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "cad\n", 4);
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    /* Disable the forced reboot, enable sending SIGINT to init. */
    reboot(RB_DISABLE_CAD);
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    while (1) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is [an easy setup to try this out](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/fde15ac9216d07c2769ab91e05abc64214f73a05#ctrl-alt-del).

Answer (score 1):

Contemporary Linux distros use `systemd` instead of SysV init. Behaviour of ctrl-alt-delete combo is handled by ctrl-alt-del.target, which is by default linked to reboot.target, but could be set to any other one.

List of targets available:

```
systemctl list-unit-files -t target
```

[Switching target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29955754/debian-jessie-shutdown-on-ctrlaltdel)

Pressing the combo 7+ times within 2 seconds (like press and hold) would force immediate reboot by default (or the action specified by `CtrlAltDelBurstAction`).

There is also useful `kbrequest.target`, but this is not enabled by default.