# How to disable ctrl-alt-del and /etc/init/control-alt-del.conf in Linux?

Tags: linux, rhel, console, init, sysvinit

My OS is RHEL 6.2

I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> by changing in `/etc/init/control-alt-del.conf` the line

```
exec /sbin/shutdown -r now "Control-alt-del pressed"
```

by

```
exec /bin/true
```

I'll be testing it next Sunday.

My questions:

1. are there any daemons to restart?
2. I keep a copy on original `/etc/init/control-alt-del.conf` in /etc/init, is it safe?
   I mean won't the shutdown part of exec be fired?
3. more official way to disable  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>?

---

**edit:**

tested on vmware player 6.0.3 (for what it is worth, this is not a virtualization issue)

1. editing file, no exec line, no restart, user logged on gui, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> : **shutdown prompt**
2. after restart, no exec line, user logged on gui, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> : **shutdown prompt**
3. after restart, exec /bin/true, user logged on gui, send
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> : **shutdown prompt**
4. after restart, exec /bin/true, **no** user logged on gui, send
       <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> : **no shutdown prompt**

Comment: Here is an init independent description of how the Linux kernel deals with Ctrl + Alt + Del: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42573/meaning-and-commands-for-ctrlaltdel/444969#444969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change in `/etc/init/control-alt-del.conf` are taken immediatly.

I tested in ESX and physical hosts.

when I inserted

```
 exec date > /var/log/cad.log
```

in `/etc/init/control-alt-del.conf`

and issue <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> I get date in `/var/log/cad.log`.

So no need to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the way to enable a function that acts on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, it is also the, probably official, point to switch if off.

You should just comment out ('#' in front of the line) the `exec shutdown...` and there is no need to insert `exec /bin/true`. No need to keep a copy of the file if you just comment things out.

I would reboot the system after the change, as I think it is init itself that reads that file, not some daemon. Just changing the file without further action doesn't have any effect¹.

¹ <sub>In the good old days you would set the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> handling in `/etc/inittab` and you could issue a `init q` after a change.</sub>

Comment: those are production system, I have no way to test it before a scheduled stop next sunday, when those will be reboted anyway.

Comment: @Archemar After the reboot things should be ok.

Comment: Why wouldn't one set the Ctrl+Alt+Del handling in `/etc/inittab` even today? RHEL 6.2 uses SysVinit.

Comment: @Gilles The /etc/inittab file is deprecated, and is now used only for setting up the default runlevel via the initdefault line. Other configuration is done via upstart jobs in the /etc/init directory.  Copied from [the Redhat Deployment site](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Technical_Notes/deployment.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the systemd world, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> is handled by [`ctrl-alt-del.target`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/systemd.special.7.html):

```
ctrl-alt-del.target
   systemd starts this target whenever Control+Alt+Del is pressed on
   the console. Usually, this should be aliased (symlinked) to
   reboot.target.
```

[To disable this target](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=53969), do:

```
systemctl mask ctrl-alt-del.target
systemctl daemon-reload
```

This does not completely disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>. Systemd has a feature where pressing that key combination more than 7 times in 2 seconds triggers an immediate reboot. I'm not sure how to disable it, but I find it useful.

I don't think it can be disabled. From [the systemd manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html):

> `SIGINT`
>
> Upon receiving this signal the systemd system manager will start the
> `ctrl-alt-del.target` unit. This is mostly equivalent to `systemctl start ctl-alt-del.target`. If this signal is received more than 7
> times per 2s, an immediate reboot is triggered. Note that pressing
> Ctrl-Alt-Del on the console will trigger this signal. Hence, if a
> reboot is hanging, pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del more than 7 times in 2s is a
> relatively safe way to trigger an immediate reboot.
>
> systemd user managers treat this signal the same way as `SIGTERM`.

Comment: Answer "borrowed" from this response to a nearly identical question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/763887/how-do-we-disable-ctrl-alt-del-on-ubuntu-16-04/763919#763919

Answer (score 0):

As of SystemD 244, there is a new feature to specifies the behavior of the ctrl-alt-del burst action (more than 7 times per 2s). From the source:

"A new setting CtrlAltDelBurstAction= has been added to /etc/systemd/system.conf which may be used to configure the precise behaviour if the user on the console presses Ctrl-Alt-Del more often than 7 times in 2s. Previously this would unconditionally result in an expedited, immediate reboot. With this new setting the precise operation may be configured in more detail, and also turned off entirely."

The possible options are: "reboot-force", "poweroff-force", "reboot-immediate", "poweroff-immediate" or disabled with "none"